# how to solve 'Undeclared Identifier' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a file called ToDoList.h and XYZToDoItem.h. XYZToDoItem.h contains the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZToDoItem : NSObject

@property NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL completed;
@property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;

@end
```

ToDoList.h contains the following:

```
#import "ToDoList.h"

@interface ToDoList ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end


@implementation ToDoList

- (void) loadInitialData {
XYZToDoItem *item1 = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init]; //<- ERROR
}
```

the error message in the last line in the latter class say the following:

1-use of undeclared identifier XYZToDoItem
2-use of Declared identifier item

please have look at the image posted below, it shows the contents and the error message in the class

please let me know why I am getting this error and how to solve it?

**image**

[image]

Comment: `#import "XYZToDoItem.h"` seems to be missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Use of undeclared identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544033/objective-c-use-of-undeclared-identifier)